# Trying to create a timestamp of every process for an order

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, pivot-table

I am trying to write a query that marks down when every step of an order happened. Like when it was ordered, when it was picked, when it was invoiced, etc.

The timestamp information is spread across multiple tables.

Here is my code:

```
Select DISTINCT
O.Company_Code
,O.Division_Code
,O.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number
,sh.PACKSLIP

,OA.Date
,OA.Action
,PA.Date
,PA.Action

,convert(datetime, LG.DATE_TIME) date
,CASE 
WHEN LG.ACTION = 'ALLOCORD'
THEN 'Allocated'
WHEN LG.ACTION = 'PICK_LP'
THEN 'Picking item ' + LG.EXTENDED
WHEN LG.ACTION = 'DNLOAD'
THEN 'DOWNLOADED'
ELSE LG.ACTION 
END ACTION

FROM
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Orders o (nolock)

LEFT JOIN 
    [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1WAREHOUSE].[dbo].SHIPHIST sh (nolock) ON o.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number = sh.cust_po


Left Join [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Order_Audit_Trail OA ON O.Company_Code = OA.Company_Code and O.Division_Code = OA.Division_Code and O.Control_Number = OA.Control_Number

Left Join [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Picktickets_Audit_Trail PA ON O.Company_Code = PA.Company_Code and O.Division_Code = PA.Division_Code and PA.Pickticket_Number = sh.packslip

LEFT JOIN [JMDNJ-ACCELSQL].[A1Warehouse].[dbo].[RF_LOG2] LG (NOLOCK) on LG.Packslip = sh.packslip

Where O.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number = '91102440'
```

This is what my results look like:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12ImY9FKCu9_ZnDosUWRxT0aBsLDq6dwKn94y8Y74Y-w/edit?usp=sharing

As you can see, it keeps duplicating. This is not correct.

How I wanted to look is something like this

```
Order-Num   Date   Action       Date  Action     Date   Action   D    Ac  
1           1PM    Order Loaded 2PM   Inserted   3PM    LG-Down  4PM  LG-Allc
2   ....
```

Or would it be better to pivot this table?

I am not quite sure how to proceed. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: what you are looking for is more of a reporting solution rather than just use SQL to get the final format of your output. see SSRS Matrix.. once you have your data.. it would be very easy to get the desired output you show in your questions

Comment: It is hard to tell without actual data, but I would say you need a `group by` to collapse multiple records into a single record. You can make your code a bit more readable by changing your case statement to ` CASE LG.ACTION
                WHEN 'ALLOCORD' THEN 'Allocated'
                WHEN 'PICK_LP' THEN 'Picking item '+LG.EXTENDED
                WHEN 'DNLOAD' THEN 'DOWNLOADED' ELSE LG.ACTION
            END AS ACTION`

Comment: Can you add sample data (considering one order) from all 5 tables? And also the expected output.